How to conditionally change template based on ACF field in WordPress 6.5 with FSE theme?
I'm currently working with WordPress 6.5 and using a Full Site Editor (FSE) theme. I need to dynamically change the template of a page based on the value of an Advanced Custom Fields (ACF) custom field. Specifically, if the custom field acf_custom_1 is true, I want the page to use a custom "Page with Sidebar" template instead of the default "Pages" template.
With "traditional" themes, I could handle this by filtering the template include, but I'm unsure how to approach this within the context of an FSE theme.
